# Not able to retrieve users location

Tags: android, android-studio

I have followed some tutorials and searched many previous StackOverflow questions on it, but I am not able to know the reason, why the user's location is not getting logged.
It might be **duplicate**, but please help me with this code

Here is my **MainActivity.java**,

```
LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListener;

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
     locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i("Location",location.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    } else {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    }


}
```

Comment: Which tutorial you followed? Can you share the link. Because from your above code snippet it is not clear the issue.

Comment: i am doing a course on udemy, so i cannot share the link :(

Comment: btw, i am using LocationManager  and a locationListener  here, and the location should be logged as i have logged it in onLocationChanged. but it is not getting logged. I have taken ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in android manifest.Is there anything else i am missing?